# Can I use Visual C++ compiler without Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Is there any way that I can use Visual C or Visual C++ compilers from the command line without having to install visual studio?

I have tried it before, and I couldn't find one. Seeking help.

Comment: The tool chain used to be included in the Windows SDK but that is no longer the case.

Comment: I think you have to install Visual Studio to get the compiler installed, but once it's installed you can execute it directly.

Comment: Usually we want opposite: Visual Studio but with another compiler ;)

Comment: If you have paid lots of money for Visual Studio, why not use all of it instead of just the compiler and the linker.

Comment: @cup - I kind of suspect the asker wants to know how to compile the project without paying a lot of money for more visual studio licenses.

Comment: Could go down the express route - licence does say you can use it for commercial.  Just that you don't get all the libraries and the ancient stuff like MFC.

Comment: cup is right, why don't just use the express edition?  Maybe someone likes to complicate its own life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, for example Windows SDK comes with a Visual C++ compiler, but it doesn't contain Visual Studio, a quick search found [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw.aspx).

LE "brilliant" decision from Microsoft: it seems that [newer Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/bg162891) doesn't come with compilers, so you need to install Visual Studio to have what to use from command line.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that the only sane option is to invoke [msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293626.aspx). Don't invoke cl.exe or link.exe directly, down that path lies madness. I've never heard of or used nmake, but it seems unnecessary.

Comment: The compiler is no longer included in the SDK. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx) - _"The Windows SDK no longer ships with a complete command-line build environment. You must install a compiler and build environment separately."_

Comment: @DanO I do cl.exe every day. And nmake too. Almost happy. I'm so mad ;)

Comment: @Drop I suppose it would work for a small project or module - but if you're maintaining a .sln why not just invoke msbuild?

Comment: @DanO .sln? no way. Only Makefiles!

Comment: DanO _nmake_ is useful for bigger projects (if those have some scripts to generate the makefiles), for example Qt is not that small.
CaptainObvlious i thought i read somewhere about that, and it seemed stupid so i had to a search to confirm, anyway i edited the answer, thank you for correction.