# Install Visual C++ Compiler on Windows without installing whole Visual Studio

Tags: c++, gcc, npm, node-gyp, browser-sync

**NOTE** This question can be duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795531/can-i-use-visual-c-compiler-without-visual-studio) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409908/using-microsoft-c-compiler-without-installing-visual-studio) question.

But please don't close it as duplicate without reading entire question.

I'm trying to install npm module [browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/) on Windows, and by reading its documentation, I found that module itself uses `node-gyp` which requires C++ compiler on Windows to build native extension. And that leads to installation of Visual Studio (community edition will do). After going through above linked questions (which I noted as duplicates of my current question), I found that Windows SDK *used* to ship with C++ compiler but now Visual Studio is required to have C++ compiler.

So my concern is, do I really need to download and install that hefty 6 GB VS Community edition just to get that C++ compiler to build `browsersync` on Windows? or is there any way to do that via GCC for Windows?

P.S. Earlier I faced similar situation for installing [node-oracledb](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb).

Thanks.

Comment: Don't know the answer, but just want you to know I faced a similar issue, and that was the reason for me to move to Golang instead of Node.JS, because in Golang you have no deploy-time dependencies to worry about. You just deploy by copying a single .exe file :-)

Comment: I recall that Windows SDK used to ship with the VC++ compiler.  Not sure if this is officially documented anywhere.

Comment: With the release of Visual Studio 2015 update 1 they are [making the C++ build tools available as a separate install](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/11/02/announcing-visual-c-build-tools-2015-standalone-c-tools-for-build-environments.aspx). I'm not sure if it has gone to RTM yet, but there is a technical preview and as far as a I know, the tools are the same as in VS2015.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Niall covered where you can get the actual C++ compiler, but if you're looking for further information on the problem there's a walkthrough on how to get `node-gyp` up and running on Windows on their [github](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-153196245) issues page with the standalone compiler.